# Having problems with putting database to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this books database and a burrows database. In burrows, there is a field for book_id and also a field for user_id, so that I can see who burrowed which book.

Now, I am trying to create a controller and view for it but it is not going well really. Right now the view is looking like this:

```
<% provide(:title, "Burrow") %>

<b align="center">Choose the name of the book you want t burrow'</b>

    <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
            <div class="forms">
                        <%= f.name %>
                        <%= f.check_box(:book_id) %>
                        <%= f.submit 'Submit!' %>
                </div>
        <% end %>
```

But this puts me to the problem where it creates an error because I want to put all books into @books in burrows controller. But I dont really see any other way?  \

The final idea would be so that I have all the books displayed and after them a checkbox, so I can select which books I want to burrow. And after that I also want a dropdown menu where all users are listed, I can choose to burrow the book for another user,  but the default value would be the logged in user but theres time till that. Right now I am struggline to understand, why my solution for listing books does not work?

Listing my controller here also:

```
class BurrowsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index,:edit,:update, :destroy]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @burrows = Burrow.all
  end

  def show
    @burrow = Burrow.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @burrow = Burrow.new
  end

  def create
    @burrow = Burrow.new(burrow_params)
    if @burrow.save
      flash[:success] = "Burrowing a book was successful!"
      redirect_to @burrow
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def listing
    @book_list = Book.all
  end

  # Private section, makes the page unable to be seen for non logged in users
  private
  def burrow_params
    params.require(:burrow).permit(:user_id, :book_id)
  end
   def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
  # Redirecting not logged in user etc.
  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to '/sessions/new', notice: "Please sign in!"
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: It's basicly giving me a first argument in form cannot contain a nil value error. So it is not getting the @book filled with book names.

Comment: Yes, it was a bit of mistype but that's how most of the code is named allready so I guess I will go with this for now..

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I am struggline to understand, why my solution for listing books does not work?

I'm not sure what listing you mean. The view you pasted apparently corresponds to the controller action `Burrows#new`?

So I'm going to tell you what's wrong with your view:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
```

This prints a form for a `Book`, not a `Burrow`. You could create a new book with this form, but that's certainly not what you're trying to do here.

---

You'll want to have all these variables in your controller:

```
def new
  @users = User.all
  @books = Book.all
  @burrow = Burrow.new
end
```

so you can use `collection_select` with `@users`, have a `@burrow` object to use with `form_for`, and do a `each` loop on `@books`, for instance, like this:

```
<%= form_for(@burrow) do |f| %>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= f.check_box :book_ids, multiple: true, book.id, nil %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.collection_select :user_id, @users, :id, :name, {}, selected: current_user.id %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Click the links for documentation on these commands: [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), [check_box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)

This is not ideal code, but it's as close to your example as I can get.

---

I understand if you don't get this right away. Your code is a bit of a mess right now and there's too much wrong with it to be explained in one post and fixed by just one line. You might want to start over, and make a **single controller action** work before you try to make everything at once.

Sometimes it's better to sit back and really think about what you're trying to achieve, and first lay out how to achieve it inside your head; and only then start programming!

It seems to me that you're using the *RailsTutorial* by **Michael Hartl**, so all I can recommend to you right now is, read what you've read again more thoroughly and try to stick to his examples first until you feel confident, before really starting to make your very own application.